# Angular - Jest : spyOnProperty (similar to jasmine)

Tags: angular, jestjs

### Please guide me create to SpyOnProperty (like Jasmine) in Jest

I am spying on a property on a child class in Jest however there is no predefined thing like `spyOnProperty()` from jasmine in jest.

How to spy on the property of a child component?

#### component

```
Class Parent {
       @ViewChild(ButtonComponent) btn: ButtonComponent;
}
```

#### spec

```
describe('ParentComponent', () => {
    //.............

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOnProperty(component.btn, 'state').and.returnValue('active); // jasmine
    jest.spyOn(component.btn, 'text', 'get').mockReturnValue('bar');// jest -> INVALID
    fixture.detectChanges();

    //----------
});
```

#### error

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given Error: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`

```
           fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
           component = fixture.componentInstance;
       >   jest.spyOn(component.btn, 'searchText', 'get').mockReturnValue('bar');
                   ^
           fixture.detectChanges();
       }));
```

Comment: Can you share your error output, please? What is invalid there?

Comment: @Tugayİlik, I updated the error in the question, please see.

Comment: You are getting this error because you are trying to spy on a property that does not exist. Does  `component.smartTable` exist? If it exists, does `component.smartTable.searchText` exists and is it a getter?

Comment: @Tugayİlik apologies for the confusion, I have edited the question. Yes, `btn` exists.

Comment: Can you add `ButtonComponent` getters code

Comment: Did you add `ButtonComponent` in `configureTestingModule declarations`?